# I'm alone, smoking

Tags: riddle

I don't know if the capitalization  has anything to do with it, or if it's just bad grammar.

> I'm alone, Smoking, Looking out to a empty street ,
>
> Who and Where am I?

(Unknown source: sent over discord)

Comment: Hi badxc and welcome to Puzzling :) Please can you let us know where this puzzle comes from? There's a site policy that all puzzles reproduced from elsewhere need to have the source cited (for many reasons, including avoiding plagiarism claims, etc.). Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha, it's done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you

> a candle on a windowsill at night?

Reasoning:

> "Alone" could refer to being the only object on the windowsill, potentially in a room empty of people, as everyone is sleeping.
>
>  "Smoking" could refer to the flame being blown out and the wick still producing smoke.
>
>  "Looking out to an empty street" could refer to the candle sitting on a windowsill in full view of the street, and the street is empty because it's night.